# What are the succes/failure conditions of boto3's ECS waiters?

Tags: boto3, amazon-ecs

Boto3 has 4 ECS waiters, ServicesStable, ServicesStopped, TasksRunning, and TasksStopped.  The documentation, however, doesn't specify what the actual success and failure conditions for those waiters are.  For example,

> Polls ECS.Client.describe_tasks() every 6 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 100 failed checks.

What do these waiters actually wait for?

Comment: You can find the rules used by the botocore code in [waiters-2.json](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/879f8440a4e9ace5d3cf145ce8b3d5e5ffb892ef/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/waiters-2.json)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got the specific configuration you were looking for but more generally if you're looking for the details of the waiter conditions in boto3 you'll navigate to the botocore [data folder](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/master/botocore/data) on github.  Then look in the subfolders for a waiters-2.json file and it will have those details.